# How can I query posts in my search bar as per the genre/tags of the post?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have made a flask website that allows users to create posts that contain at least one image (1 post can contain more than one image).
I have attempted to make a search bar that is practical, but can also be made by a newbie at programming too.
I have not used any AI or algorithms, just some simple instructions in the form of code.
The following is the code I have written for the backend of the search bar:

```
@app.route('/search-result/<string:manga_name>')
def search_result(manga_name):
    posts = Image.query.filter_by(manga_name = manga_name).all()
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=manga_name).first() #current user might search for the username of a user instead of a manga name
    tag = Tags.query.filter_by(tag=manga_name).all()
    if posts != None and user != None and tag != None: #priotritizing username over tags and post names
        num_of_posts = len(list(posts))
        user_posts = Image.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id)
        num_of_posts = len(list(posts))
        num_of_user_posts = len(list(user_posts))
        return render_template('searchresult.html', posts=posts, posts_num = num_of_posts, num_of_user_posts=num_of_user_posts, user_posts=user_posts)
    elif posts != None: #querying posts as per their name
        num_of_posts = len(list(posts))
        num_of_user_posts = 0
        return render_template('searchresult.html', posts=posts, posts_num = num_of_posts, num_of_user_posts=num_of_user_posts)
    elif user != None: #querying as per usernames
        num_of_posts = 0
        user_posts = Image.query.filter_by(user_id=user.id)
        num_of_user_posts = len(list(user_posts))
        return render_template('searchresult.html', posts_num = num_of_posts, num_of_user_posts=num_of_user_posts, user_posts=user_posts)
    elif tag != None: #querying as per tags
        pass
```

I take input from the user (on my index page) from the search bar of their browser and store it in a variable called manga_name.
I first  check if a post exists by querying the Image table (This is not the Posts table but I am directly querying the images of various posts as per their
manga_name variable as it is more efficient, you will understand what I mean after you see the database models)
I am also then querying the users table to see if what the user entered was a username instead of the name of a post.
Then I am querying the tags table as that is the last possibility that the user did not enter a username or a name of the post but a tag like "action",
"fantasy", "horror" etc.
Then I have various if else statements that return different outputs based on which type of content the user searched for.
The following are the relevant database models:

```
class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    # post_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='Posts', passive_deletes=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='Posts', passive_deletes=True)
class Tags(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=True)
class Post_Tags(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    profile_pic = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, default="profile-icon.png")
    is_moderator = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Posts', backref='author', lazy=True)
    # liked_posts = db.relationship('Image', secondary=posts_liked_by_users, backref='user_that_liked')
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='user', passive_deletes=True)
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='user', passive_deletes=True)

    def get_reset_token(self):
        encoded = jwt.encode({'user_id':self.id, "exp":datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours = 0.5)}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithm='HS256')
        return encoded
    @staticmethod
    def verify_secret_token(token):
        try:
            decoded = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False})
            user_id = decoded['user_id']
            
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.username}, {self.email}'

class Image(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title=db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc))
    img_location = db.Column(db.String(600), nullable=False)
    mimetype = db.Column(db.String(10))
    post_name = db.Column(db.String(150),nullable=False, unique=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    manga_name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=False)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id', ), nullable=False)
```

In the block of code having the comment "querying as per tags", I have just added a pass statement as I am confused regarding how I should go about this.
I want to display the posts having the tag(s) that a user entered in the search bar.
Let us take the previous example I mentioned, suppose the user enters "action fantasy horror" as the input in the search bar
I want the code to be able to query the posts that have at least one of those tags. If one post has more than one tag, I still don't want it to appear more than once on the page.
To get the posts to be displayed, I will need to somehow to get the posts that have those particular tags, and then query all the images associated with that post and then display those. (you can check the other if else statements in the search result route for reference)
If I am not mistaken, I think what I want to do can be done using an inner join in sqlalchemy but I am having a really tough time just learning how to do that and I do not know how I will implement it in this case.
The following is the search-result template:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.93);">
        <div id="content-1" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
            {% if (posts_num == 0) and (num_of_user_posts == 0) %}
                <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; width: 300px;">
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 35px; color: white;">0 results</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                {% if (posts_num > 0) %}
                    {% for post in posts %}
                        {% if loop.changed(post.post_name) %}
                            <div class="content-items">
                                <a href="{{ url_for('read', post_name=post.post_name) }}">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=post.post_name+'/'+post.title) }}" alt="" class="content-images" style="max-height: 1028px; max-width: 609px; object-fit: contain;">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% elif (num_of_user_posts > 0) %}
                    {% for post in user_posts %}
                        {% if loop.changed(post.post_name) %}
                            <div class="content-items">
                                <a href="{{ url_for('read', post_name=post.post_name) }}">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=post.post_name+'/'+post.title) }}" alt="" class="content-images" style="max-height: 1028px; max-width: 609px; object-fit: contain;">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If possible, please help me with the coding part of the solution too!
Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Which db you use? I'd look into the "full-text search" functionality of the database.

Comment: I am currently using a SQLite database for developing but I will most likely either use Postgres or MySQL for the actual app. And thanks, I will look into it :) @NeilMcGuigan